# Postgres to_timestamp setting timezone to +1

Tags: postgresql, to-timestamp

I am using the to_timestamp function in Postgres to convert an integer value to a timestamp. When I do this, the timezone is set to +1, adding an hour to the stored time.

I am located in the UK so the current timezone offset should be +0, not +1.

Does anyone know how to stop this/set the timezone manually?

Example:

```
UPDATE my_table SET date_time_updated = to_timestamp(0) where id = 1;
SELECT date_time_updated FROM my_table WHERE id = 1; //Would expect midnight 01/01/1970

   date_time_updated
------------------------
 1970-01-01 01:00:00+01
(1 row)
```

Comment: Why the obfuscation with an integer? Why not use `date_time_update = timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00'`? Or maybe even better `date_time_update = '-infinity'`?

Comment: Sorry I probably should have explained, I need to use an integer as I am using Javascript to calculate a random epoch time and then using this to set the timestamp. 01/01/1970 was just an example to demonstrate that even when I try and use 0 it is not set to the Unix epoch as it should be (due to the timezone adding an hour).

Comment: It is set to the Unix epoch as it should be because epoch time is **always** in the UTC time zone. Try `select extract (epoch from '1970-01-01 01:00:00+01'::timestamptz)` - it returns 0. To achieve what you need use `select to_timestamp(0)::timestamptz at time zone 'utc'`

Comment: Thanks, that works for me

Answer (score 0):

Internally, the `timestamp with time zone` is time zone agnostic (weird as it sounds).

When PostgreSQL converts it to a string, it formats it according to the current setting of the `timezone` parameter.

So change your session's time zone with

```
SET timezone = 'Europe/London';
```

To change the default value that is used unless the client overrides it, change the parameter in `postgresql.conf` and reload PostgreSQL.